# regex split on character when not followed by other characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split on the character `-` when not followed by `CMB`

**Example**

Test data

```
abcd-sdfsdf-cmb
sdfsdf-cmb
```

Intended Output

```
abcd
sdfsdf-cmb

abcd-cmb
sdfsdf
```

**What I have so far**

```
Regex.Split(operation, @"-+")
```

which returns

```
abcd
sdfsdf
cmb

abcd
cmb
sdfsdf
```

### Note

The above just returns a split on `-`, however I'm not sure how to look ahead for the `CMB`.

Comment: I don't see anything related to `CMB` in your regex.. Seems like you posted a random regex just to say *this is what I have tried*

Comment: I didn't know how to do it unfortunatly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
Regex.Split(operation, @"-(?!cmb)")
```

`(?!cmb)` is a negative lookahead which means match `-` only when it is not followed by `cmb`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Negative Lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to achieve this.

```
Regex.Split(operation, @"-(?!(?i:cmb))")
```

The lookahead asserts that what immediately follows `-` in the string is not "CMB". The inline modifier `(?i: ... )` is used to match the substring in a case-insensitive manner.